# Noncritical Level Lines of Energy in Arnold' book about ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

I am trying to understand the follwoing from Arnold's book about ODEs:

**In the second to last line it says that "the integral converges, since $U'(a),U'(b)\neq 0$". Why do we need that for the convergence? But doesn't he actually mean just the existence of the intergral**

Many Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since $U(a)=U(b)=E$ you get that
$$
E-U(\xi)=U'(a)(\xi-a)+\frac{U''(a)}{2}(\xi-a)^2+\dots,
$$
If you assume that $U'(a)=0$ then the corresponding improper integral diverges.

Comment: Is this because we end up with $\frac{U''}{2}(\xi-a^2)$ in the denominator, if we expand it for n=2. and this integral diverges? Analogously for the other singularity?

Comment: Integral $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x^p}$ converges for $p<1$.

Comment: Can't I also argue that if "U'(a)=0",then,since $U'(x)=-F(x)=x''=v'=\sqrt(2(E-U(x)))$, we have a singularity at $x=a$. Thus, it does not converge?

Comment: I answered your question, and I am not sure what you are asking in the last comment. It actually could be both cases, either $U'(a)=0$ or $U'(a)\neq 0$, in the copied extract Arnold considers the latter one.

Comment: In the last comment I am asking if I could't conclude from the fact that $U'(x)=\sqrt(2(E-U(x)))$ that we need $U'(a),U'(b)\neq 0$.